# Different way to solve $|x-3|<|2x|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I know two ways I can solve $|x-3|<|2x|$

1. By squaring both sides
2. By interpreting the inequality as a statement about distances on the real line.

Question: How can I solve this inequality algebraically, but without squaring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By a discussion based on the sign rule for the absolute value:

$$t\ge0\implies|t|=t,t\le0\implies |t|=-t.$$

Here you have three cases

$$\begin{align}x\le0&\implies |x-3|<|2x|\equiv -x+3<-2x\\
0\le x\le3&\implies |x-3|<|2x|\equiv -x+3<2x\\
x \ge3&\implies |x-3|<|2x|\equiv\ \ \ x-3<2x.\end{align}$$

Then you solve the three inequations and match the solutions against the three sub-domains.

Answer (score 2):

Check for critical points 
i.e. $x-3=0$ and $2x=0$
this will give you $x=3$ and $x=0$,
thus your real lines is divided into 3 parts,$(-\infty,0)$,$[0,3)$,$[3,+\infty)$,
now solve your equation in each of these intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the following cases

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  x \ge 3\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x - 3 < 2x\, \hfill \cr 
  0 < x < 3\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - (x - 3) < 2x \hfill \cr 
  x \le 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - (x - 3) <  - 2x \hfill \cr}  \right.$$